# Make Angular / RxJS more readable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm relatively new to RxJs and angular in general and wanted to know if there's a way to simplify the following code so it still does the same thing but is easier to read or is this as good as it can be?

```
private configureDS() {

let params$ = this.params$.pipe(debounceTime(300));
this.user$
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(user =>
      from(this.loadPosts(user)).pipe(map(posts => ({ user, posts })))
    ),
    combineLatest(this.dates$, params$),
    switchMap(([{ user, posts }, dates, params]) =>
      from(
        this.loadData(dates.date, dates.endDate, user, posts, params)
      ).pipe(map(data => ({ dates, data })))
    )
  )
  .subscribe(({ dates, data }) => this.displayData(data, dates));

this.paramsSubject.next(this.params);

}
```

Comment: it's was much better without the pipe operater

Comment: You could create named functions instead of arrow functions to make it more compat and readable.

Comment: Apparently, pipe is the way to go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCXZhe6KsxQ

Comment: Noted @ibenjelloun

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to improve readability a bit

```
let params$ = this.params$.pipe(debounceTime(300));
let userPosts$ = this.user$
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(user =>
      from(this.loadPosts(user)).pipe(map(posts => ({ user, posts })))
    ),
  );

combineLatest(userPosts$, this.dates$, params$)
.pipe(
    switchMap(([{ user, posts }, dates, params]) =>
      from(
        this.loadData(dates.date, dates.endDate, user, posts, params)
      ).pipe(map(data => ({ dates, data })))
    )
)
.subscribe(({ dates, data }) => this.displayData(data, dates));
```

This basically uses the `combineLatest` function instead of the `combineLatest` operator (which is depracted since RxJs 6).

Still there are some things not really clear to me. For instance, why to you use the `from` function with `this.loadPosts(user)`? Usually `from` takes an `iterable` as input and returns a stream which emits per each element of the `iterable` - is `loadPosts` returning an `iterable`?

I ask these questions because maybe readability can be improved reviewing a bit the design of the chain.

Comment: Thanks. This is the signature for loadPosts: `loadPosts(user: User): Promise<Post[]>`

Comment: OK. What I understand now is that you have 3 streams of data: user$, params$ and date$ - each of these stream can emit autonomously a new value. Any time any of these streams emits, then you want to run `loadData` and display the new data. If this is the case, then I do not see much space for improving readability. It this is not the case, then I have not understood the context.

Comment: Okay, in that case, I should probably close this question. SO isn't letting me though.